# receiving everyday XML files - 12 types need to do search on these everyday

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

Asp.NET - C#.NET

I need a advice regarding a design problem below:

I'll receive everyday XML files. It changes the quantity e.g. yesterday 10 XML files received, today XML 56 files received and maybe tomorrow 161 XML files etc.

There are 12 types (12 XSD)... and in the top there is a attribute called FormType e.g. FormType="1", FormType="2" , FormType="12" etc. up to 12 formtypes.

All of them have common fields like Name, adres, Phone.
But e.g. FormType=1 is for Construction, FormType=2 is for IT, FormType 3=Hospital, Formtype=4 is for Advertisement etc. etc.

As I said all of them have common attributes.

**Requirements:**
Need a search screen so the user can do search on these XML contents. But I don't have any clue how to approach this. e.g. Search the text in some attributes for the xml's received from Date_From and Date_To.

**Problem:**
I've heard about putting the XML's in a Binary field and do XPATH query or whatever but don't know the word's to search on google.

I was thinking to create a big database.table and read all XML's and put in the Database Table. But the issue is some xml attributes are very huge like 2-3 pages. and the same attributes in other XML file are empty.. 
So creating NVARCHAR(MAX)  for every XML attribute and putting them in table.field.... After some period my DATABASE will be a big big monster...

Can someone advice what is the best approach to handle this issue?

Comment: I would suggest you to save all the file's XML (complete XML) in a single field of a table e.g. MyTable having fields, date , XML(nvarchar(max)) and then search them through sql, in a storedprocedure maybe, like  select * from OPENXML() . just a suggestion you can dig into more by yourself if it suits your purpos

Comment: do you mean create a field nvarchar(max) e.g. name XMLREceives. and save the XML in this field by StreamWriter (read XML and write whole XML into this field)? and what about the search? e.g. location is "Chicago" do I need to read all records and use XMLDocument to check the location attribute whether it contains Chicago or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem.  I'm guessing that the query's supposed to return individual XML documents that meet some kind of user-specified criteria.

In that event, my starting point would probably be to implement a method for querying a single XML document, i.e. one that returns true if the document's a hit and false otherwise.  In all likelihood, I'd make the query parameter an XPath query, but who knows?  Here's a simple example:

```
public bool TestXml(XDocument d, string query)
{
   return d.XPathSelectElements(query).Any();
}
```

Next, I need a store of XML documents to query.  Where does that store live, and what form does it take?  At a certain level, those are implementation details that my application doesn't care about.  They could live in a database, or the file system.  They could be cached in memory.  I'd start by keeping it simple, something like:

```
public IEnumerable<XDocument> XmlDocuments()
{
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(XmlDirectoryPath);
   foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
   {
      yield return XDocument.Load(fi.Filename);
   }
}
```

Now I can get all of the documents that fulfill a request like this:

```
public IEnumerable<XDocument> GetDocuments(query)
{
   return XmlDocuments.Where(x => TextXml(x, query));
}
```

The thing that jumps out at me when I look at this problem:   I have to parse my documents into `XDocument` objects to query them.  That's going to happen whether they live in a database or the file system.  (If I stick them in a database and write a stored procedure that does XPath queries, as someone suggested, I'm still parsing all of the XML every time I execute a query; I've just moved all that work to the database server.)

That's a lot of I/O and CPU time that gets spent doing the exact same thing over and over again.  If the volume of queries is anything other than tiny, I'd consider building a `List<XDocument>` the first time `GetDocuments()` is called and come up with a scheme of keeping that list in memory until new XML documents are received (or possibly updating it when new XML documents are received).

Comment: Hi Robert, thans for replying. Well I got your explanation, but please clarify me also his situtaion: I'll receive daily approx. 50 XML's shall I store the XML in DATABASE? How? just as VARCHAR(NOMAX) or shall I put them as external file in a Folder on Network and read them when Criteria is met on the Search? At End of year I'll have 50.000 XML's so I need to find out a way to store them at a place. So the question is then shall I put them in DATABASE as TEXT or different and read with XDOCUMENT or shall I save them in a folder and use FileInfo-direcotry.getfiles() etc. please advice on this?

Comment: Well, the main point of my answer is that where you physically store the XML documents is an implementation detail that's distinct from the problem of parsing and querying.  Put them in a database or put them in a file system, the above still works.  Although if you're going to have 50,000 of them, you'd better find a way of reducing the number of them that you need to search (since you have to parse a document to query it) when the user enters a query, some non-XML data elements that can be indexed - and then yes, I'd use a database.

Comment: Robert, one more question regardgin this: Would you save them in Database as just text like whole XML in a column NVarchar(nomax)? or would you use another column format to reduce the size? I mean I need to let them search on 50.000 XMl's for at least 2 years which is 100.000 active XML's. so would you still store the 1 XML in 1 column and create separate columns for the search parts in Database? columnName, ColumnAdres, ColumnCity..., ColumnXMLContent. ColumnXMLContent is the whole conent XML file. please advice ?

Comment: If you want to give users the ability to search the content of 100,000 active XML files at once, you need to rethink the problem.  The most important thing you can ask yourself is not "what format should I store these documents in?" but rather "what can I do to reduce the number of documents any individual query examines?"  So yes, I'd extract data elements from the XML into columns in the table if it were at all possible, and only search the XML itself as a last resort.